# Populate Listview from string array source, with a String ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, arrays, android-layout, listview, android-arrayadapter

I need to populate a listview with an array from string resources. How do I pass the array to my adapter? When I try following I get the error below

```
ArrayAdapter zooAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.animals, android.R.id.text1);
zooList.setAdapter(zooAdapter);
zooList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

Other than resource not found, I am not sure what to make of the error log. But then all my resources are there, I got no error from eclipse. **In any case, what I need to do is load my arrayAdapter with data from an Array resource, does anyone know how to do that?**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File  from xml type layout resource ID #0x1020014
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2184)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2139)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:891)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:371)
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2306)
    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1244)
    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1156)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15293)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1418)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:709)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:602)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15293)
    at android.widget.SlidingDrawer.onMeasure(SlidingDrawer.java:270)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15293)
    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:630)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15293)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15293)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1418)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:709)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:602)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15293)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2425)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15293)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1876)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1112)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1301)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1010)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4255)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4849)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
    at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlAssetNative(Native Method)
    at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlBlockAsset(AssetManager.java:487)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2166)
    ... 48 more
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two wrong things I can see in your code:

1 -  You don't get the array correctly:

```
getResources().getStringArray(R.array.animals);
```

2 - You don't pass a row layout to your Adapter

```
// Create an ArrayAdapter from the String Array.
final ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> aa =
    ArrayAdapter.createFromResource
    (
        getActivity(), values, R.layout.list_row
    );
```

In this case is a custom row

All together:

```
// Create an ArrayAdapter from the String Array.
final ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> aa =
    ArrayAdapter.createFromResource
    (
        getActivity(), getResources().getStringArray(R.array.animals), R.layout.list_row
    );
```

Answer (score 4):

You can follow this too:

1) Store your string array in String[] variable, now this is going to be your  source data.

2) Define ArrayAdapter, this will let you, how to represent your source data.

Now how to do that?

```
String[] zooString=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.animals);
ArrayAdapter<String> zooAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, zooString);

zooList.setAdapter(zooAdapter);
zooList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});
```